# Laptop boots only after a couple of tries?

Tags: windows, boot, hardware-failure

My windows laptop can boot only after a few tries, before that it either gets stuck on the logo or just a black screen. Also, camera light starts blinking when booting up, and it never did that. I tried reinstalling windows as well as trying out ubuntu, and the problem persisted. Apart from that, once it boots, everything works great. I know it's probably a hw issue, but I'm not sure what it can be.

Comment: Get the manufacturer's hardware diagnostic app on USB and test the hardware.

Comment: any external drives attached over USB?

Answer (score 0):

Boot time is the most demanding as regarding power consumption.

It's possible that your power-supply (PSU) has weakened, especially
if the laptop is not new (which model?).
If you have recently replaced some component, it might be that the
new component is more demanding on electricity.

But it's also possible that some weak connection on the
motherboard expands after the laptop warms up after being
turned on for some time.

I can advise you to replace the PSU. As this costs money, if you don't
have one available, better buy from a vendor with a good return
policy.
I remark that having the laptop cared for by a professional will
assure that you only pay for the components you really need.